# Django 1.6 test discovery cannot find test modules

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

Django 1.6.10 cannot find test modules located outside my apps when  running any of these code (ref:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests)

```
./manage.py test tests/app1/
./manage.py test tests/app1/test_views
```

I keep getting these errors

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label tests/app1/ could not be found

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label tests/app1/test_views could not be found
```

Here is my project structure:

```
- project
    - app1
        - __init__.py
        - models.py
        - views.py
        - forms.py
        - admins.py
    - app2
        - ..as per above
    - tests
        - __init__.py (blank)
        - app1
           - __init__.py (blank)
           - test_views.py
           - test_forms.py
        - app2
           - __init__.py (blank)
           - test_views.py
           - test_walkthrough.py
```

I read Django Discovery runner a few times and still cannot find out where did I go wrong.  Any help please - what do I miss

Replacing / with . gives the same error however when execute

```
./manage.py test tests.app1.test_views.MyTestCase
./manage.py test tests.app1.test_views.MyTestCase.test_mymethod
```

I get ValueError.

```
ValueError: Test label  'tests.app1.test_views.MyTestCase.test_mymethod' should be of the form app.TestCase or app.TestCase.test_method
```

Further update:
I finally got it to work when adding --testrunner='django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner' to the command line.  As per Django doc, any of these patterns works now (using / is a way of providing a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory):.

```
./manage.py test --testrunner='django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner' tests.app1
./manage.py test --testrunner='django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner' tests.app1.test_views.MyTestCase
./manage.py test --testrunner='django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner' tests/app1/
```

Still do not know why I have to provide --testrunner value.  I am using Mezzanine in my code too and have double confirmed that settings.TEST_RUNNER is pointing to django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner

Can anyone help explaining why do I need --testrunner flag in django 1.6?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did my solution not work for you?

Comment: Replacing / with .(dot) did not work.  I was using that convention before when I have each app tests under its own directory.  I prefer to have Test separate from my code and thus when changing to this file structure, django Discovery does not seem to find the tests.

Answer (score 3):

You should be referring to them as modules, not paths:

```
./manage.py test tests.app1
./manage.py test tests.app1.test_views
```

Read more about running tests [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests).

Comment: This does not work.  I also tried configure configuring (which I don't think it is required given that i am using 1.6.10) TEST_DISCOVER_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "tests") and check that it is pointing to correct path in my settings.py.  Still no joy.

Comment: This *does* work. This is how Python references modules. At the very least, doing this should raise a different error. What error do you get when you use this?

Comment: I get this error:  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label tests could not be found.   Between, must I include this tests directory in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I tried adding tests dir to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.  Then executing ./manage.py test tests.app1.test_views   I get this error: ValueError: Test label 'tests.app1.test_views' does not refer to a test.   But if i move test_views.py under app1/tests directory then it works ok.  I thought with Django 1.6, it should discover test even if tests are not in app dir.

Comment: got it to work now by adding  --testrunner='django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'   Not sure why that is required even though the TEST_RUNNER is pointing to django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner